# Azure DevOps Pipeline build trigger with path filter not working for folder name with whitespace

Tags: azure-devops, build, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-pipelines, cicd

I'm setting up build trigger when commit is made to a specific folder. However the folder name has whitespace and that is not being accepted. Assume below to be my folder structure, I want to trigger build if any changes to files in "test folder"  (Whitespace included)

```
root
|--test folder
   |--file1.txt
```

Below is the trigger I set in pipeline

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
     include:
       - test folder/*
```

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you put the path in quotes

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
  paths:
     include:
       - "test folder/*"
```